# Dependency injection setters in a base class and having classes requring dependencies as extensions

Tags: php, dependency-injection

If I'm using setters for dependency injection, and a number of classes all require the same dependencies, should I have all those classes extend a base class with the setters for dependencies in it?

So for example:

Say I have three classes: Page, Article, Comment, all of which depend on $db and $user.

What are the benefits or disadvantages of having a base class Dependencies, something like this:

```
    class Dependencies
    {
        private $database;
        private $user;
        final public function setDatabase($dbh)
        {
            $this->database = $dbh;
        }

        final public function setUser($user)
        {
            $this->user = $user;
        }
    }
```

and then having he other classes as extensions of Dependencies

```
class Article extends Dependencies
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // some code
    }

    // some other functions that use $this->database and $this->user
}
```

rather than having setDatabase and setUser exist inside each of the separate classes (Article, Page and Comment).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Having a class named Dependencies is bad news. An article isn't a sub-type of dependencies.

This is where traits could be more appropriate.

```
trait DatabaseOwner
{
  private $database;

  final public function setDatabase($dbh)
  {
    $this->database = $dbh;
  }
}

class Article
{
  use DatabaseOwner;
}
```

You can create traits that consist of multiple traits if you find yourself often using the same set together.

However, all that said: If those three classes all descend from some better named class that represents an is-a relationship and it implements those functions (or uses the traits) because it is intrinsic to the base type, then that is perfectly acceptable.

But creating a monolithic base class just because things happen to share some properties isn't good in my opinion.

Comment: Appropriate use of traits no doubt, but worth mentioning they're only available from php5.4 onwards